# File url check in php

Tags: php

I am trying to download a file and put its contents into the db using php. I am able to do that. But what if i have to check the url first and then if it exists, download, else report failure. How am i to do that?

say: $url = "...";

I need a condition:

if(file in the url exists)

{

```
      report success;

      download;
```

}

else

```
       report failure;
```

Comment: @aendrew and geoff: The error "... failed to open HTTP stream....." should not be printed. say I must catch the error and display it in my own terms..

Comment: With my code, you should not encounter any errors, as the @ symbol is used to suppress warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following code below to check if the file exists or not.

```
<?
$ct = @file_get_contents($url)

if(($ct != false)&&($ct != '')) {
//The file exists
}
?>
```

If the resource might take a long time to fetch, then you can set a timeout like this:

```
// Create the stream context
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
'timeout' => 5      // Timeout in seconds
)
));

// Fetch the URL's contents
$contents = @file_get_contents($this->url, 0, $context);

// Check for empties
if (!empty($contents)) {
//The file exists

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (fopen($url)) { 
  report success; 
  download; 
} 
else { 
   report failure
}`

...Should do the trick.

Add an @ symbol before the function to prevent error output; so:

`if (@fopen($url)) { 
  report success; 
  download; 
} 
else { 
   report failure
}`

Comment: yes, but the file might be empty, in which case fopen would return ok

Comment: but what if the file does not exist .. the msg i showd will be printed

Comment: Yes, but the question wasn't whether the file had contents; the question was whether the file exists.

Comment: whether the file exists or not. If the file exists, how can it be empty

Comment: Change fopen(); to @fopen(); -- the @ suppresses error messages.

Comment: @aendrew: That works.. Thanks mate.. By the by is @ mainly used for suppressing error msgs